# Can I copy a deleted GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to copy GameObject(enemy) in a circle radius around the player. I've got that part but i need to delete the original GameObject(The One that I am copying). I am thinking of somehow saving the one that I am copying but I don't really know. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually delete it (destroy it), copy won't work.

You can:

- copy it before deleting
- disable the GameObject (go.[setActive(false)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)).
- Instantiate a new gameobject, instead of copying.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer! If you have the same problem, just deactivate the original object.

Comment: basically my answer :)